# Can't Filter for Value Inside Array in MongoDB Compass

Tags: arrays, mongodb, filter, filtering, mongodb-compass

I have the following record structure:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "609224f28062c60008143024"
    },
    "attachments": [""],
    "taggedUsers": [],
    "parentIds": ["609224f05806bd0008055521"],
    "user": [{
        "email": "mark@place.com",
        "firstName": "Mark",
        "lastName": "Place",
        "isSendEmail": true,
        "isSendSms": false,
        "phone": "",
        "userId": 991   <--- I want to filter for this value
    }],
    "pinnedBy": [],
    "likedBy": [],
    "referenceId": {
        "$oid": "609224f05806bd0008055521"
    },
    "message": "Julio is my neighbor",
    "created": {
        "$date": "2016-12-15T01:23:34.000Z"
    },
    "source": "Smartboard",
    "threadId": "f763d281f8fc29e29f7906c15da368c2f5a2231a",
    "__v": 0,
    "preferences": [{
        "private_note": 0
    }]
}
```

I want to Filter for all records with a 'userId' of 991 and display all fields, but I can't figure out how to structure the Filter properly – it always says it can't find any records. It seems like
`{ user: [{ 0: { userId: 991 } }] }` should work, but neither that nor several variations of brackets and braces has worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Query

- i think you want to keep the documents that have that user
- `$in` will be true if the array `[991]` contains at least one user of the
  `user.userId` array (the array with all the users ids)

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NplZ71tHZoa)

```js
db.collection.find({
  "user.userId": {
    "$in": [
      991
    ]
  }
})
```